# How would banned magic be used by the Empire for their infrastructure and cities?

Tags: magic, pre-industrial

In a world similar to LoTR where the Empire of the Elves have conquered the world and has banned/forbidden all use of magic by all Citizens, how would the Empire apply magical means for the infrastructure their cities? (Because no matter what, magic still exists all around them in their world.) For example, the Empire has its own Institution that trains a limited number of mages in the art of magic who then magically create superheat by magically fusing atoms which then can be used as energy and electricity through magical means which then gives their cities and homes heat and electricity through magical means, not science. In this way magical means is allowed but only by the Empire's trained magical experts. What are some other ways magic can be used to improve the infrastructure of their cities and homes without using science in this pre-industrial society? It would be extremely limited due to the Law of the Empire. As such, there would be no equilivant of washing machines, dishwashers, televisions, and so on. However heat, electricity, floating wagons/buses/trains pulled by horses or oxen and so on would be allowed to improve life in the cities which does not use any science at all. No copper wires, no piping, no magitek. What other magical means could be used to improve their cities without giving their citizens magical means as well?

Comment: Isn't this brainstorming?

Comment: It reads like you have it figured out.   Public utilities and government services are magic.  Private things and things for individual use are nonmagic.